# Compilation error with a shared library in C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I'm currently coding a shared library in C, I'm trying to compile with a test hand next to it but I get the following error:

```bash
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g3 -I../includes -L../build -lc main.o -o test
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in the "main" function :
main.c:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to "my_strlen".
collect2: error: ld returned output status 1
make: *** [Makefile:12: test] Error 1
```

Here's my project tree :

```bash
.
├── build
│   └── vlibc.so
├── includes
│   └── vlibc.h
├── Makefile
├── src
│   ├── memory
│   │   ├── memdump.c
│   │   ├── memdump.o
│   │   ├── my_free.c
│   │   ├── my_free.o
│   │   ├── my_memcmp.c
│   │   ├── my_memcmp.o
│   │   ├── my_memcpy.c
│   │   ├── my_memcpy.o
│   │   ├── my_memove.c
│   │   ├── my_memove.o
│   │   ├── my_memset.c
│   │   └── my_memset.o
│   └── string
│       ├── my_strlen.c
│       └── my_strlen.o
└── tests
    ├── main.c
    ├── main.o
    └── Makefile
```

Here is the Makefile of the test binary :

```bash
INC = -I../includes
EXE_NAME = test
SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g3
LFLAGS = -L../build -lc

all: $(EXE_NAME)

$(EXE_NAME): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) $(LFLAGS) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)

clean-all: clean
    rm -f $(EXE_NAME)

re-lib:
    $(MAKE) -C .. re
    $(MAKE) -C .. clean

re: re-lib all clean
```

My lib's Makefile :

```bash
CC              =   gcc
CFLAGS          =   -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g3
INC             =   -I./includes
SRC             :=  $(shell find src/ -type f -name '*.c')
OBJ             :=  $(SRC:.c=.o)
BUILD_DIR       =   build/
LIB_NAME        =   vlibc.so

START_TIME      :=  $(shell date +%s%3N)

FORCE_REBUILD   ?=  0

GREEN = \033[1;32m
YELLOW = \033[1;33m
CYAN = \033[1;36m
RESET = \033[0m

ifeq ($(FORCE_REBUILD),1)
    OBJ :=
endif

$(BUILD_DIR)$(LIB_NAME): $(OBJ)
    @$(CC) -fno-builtin -shared -o $@ $(OBJ) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) $(args)
    @END_TIME=$$(date +%s%3N); \
    echo -e "$(GREEN)[VLibC]$(RESET) - $(YELLOW)[INFO]$(RESET) "\
    "Compilation done in $(CYAN)$$(($$END_TIME - $(START_TIME))) ms$(RESET)"

%.o: %.c
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -fPIC -c $< -o $@

clean:
    @rm -f $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
    @rm -f $(BUILD_DIR)$(LIB_NAME)

re: FORCE_REBUILD = 1
re: fclean $(BUILD_DIR)$(LIB_NAME)

.PHONY: clean fclean re
```

I'd like to point out that I don't encounter any errors when compiling my lib. Also, my_strlen() is included in the header file.

vlibc.h :

```c
#ifndef VLIBC_VERBOSE
    #define VLIBC_VERBOSE 0
#endif

#ifndef VLIBC_H_
    #define VLIBC_H_

/* Includes */
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* Colors */
#define COLOR_SIZE 8
#define COLOR_RESET_SIZE 5
#define BLACK "\033[0;30m"
#define RED "\033[0;31m"
#define GREEN "\033[0;32m"
#define YELLOW "\033[0;33m"
#define BLUE "\033[0;34m"
#define RESET "\033[0m"

/* Log's prompt*/
#define ERROR "\033[0;32m[VLibC]\033[0m - \033[0;31m[ERROR]\033[0m"
#define WARNING "\033[0;32m[VLibC]\033[0m - \033[0;33m[WARNING]\033[0m"
#define INFO "\033[0;32m[VLibC]\033[0m - \033[0;34m[INFO]\033[0m"

/* System's macros*/
#define IS_BIG_ENDIAN (!*(unsigned char *)&(uint16_t){1})

/* Magic numbers */
#define JPEG_MAGIC_NUMBER_SIZE 3
#define JPEG_MAGIC_NUMBER {0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF}
#define ELF_MAGIC_NUMBER_SIZE 16
#define ELF_MAGIC_NUMBER {0x7f, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x46, \
    0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, \
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, \
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}
/* Typedef */
typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef byte *byte_ptr;

/* Memory */
void memdump(void *p, size_t size, bool color);
void my_free(void **ptr);
int my_memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);
void *my_memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
void *my_memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
void *my_memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);

/* String */
size_t my_strlen(const char *str);

#endif
```

main.c :

```c
#include <vlibc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int ac, char **av, char **env)
{
    (void) ac, (void) av, (void) env;
    const char *str = "Hello, World!\n";
    printf("GLIBC strlen : %zu, VLIBC strlen : %zu\n", strlen(str), my_strlen(str));
    return (0);
}
```

[UPDATE]

Following the comments I have replaced  `LFLAGS = -L../build -lc` with `LFLAGS = -L../build -lvlibc` I now get the following error:

```bash
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g3 -I../includes -L../build -lvlibc main.o -o test
/usr/bin/ld: can't find -lvlibc: No such file or folder
collect2: error: ld returned output status 1
make: *** [Makefile:12: test] Error 1
```

Yet `vlibc.so` exists in `../build`

Comment: You're not linking against `vlibc.so`.

Comment: Like @Siguza said you need to add `-lvlibc` to the arguments for compiling *main.c* into an executable. The compiler doesn't magically know to link against your library -- you have to tell it to do so.

Comment: Note that `my_strlen()` is declared in your header; it is not defined there (and it should not be defined there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original problem:

> ```
> gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g3 -I../includes -L../build -lc main.o -o test
> ```

1. You have `-lc` in the wrong place (it should *follow* `main.o`, not precede it).
2. You are not linking against `vlibc.so`

The new problem:

> ```
> gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g3 -I../includes -L../build -lvlibc main.o -o test
> ```

The argument `-lvlibc` tells the linker: find a library named `libvlibc.a` or `libvlibc.so` and link against that. Since no such library exists, the linker complains: `can't find -lvlibc`.

Solution: don't name your library `vlibc.so`, name it `libvlibc.so`, so you don't have to do anything special at link time.

If for some reason you insist on naming the library without `lib` prefix, you can still link against it with either:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g3 -I../includes -L../build main.o -l:vlibc.so -o test
```

or

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g3 -I../includes main.o ../build/vlibc.so -o test
```

Note: you will probably also need to either add `-rpath` (preferred) or set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so the dynamic linker can find `{lib}vlibc.so` at runtime.